# Post JSON Multipart-Data with retofit android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to simulate this request as in this picture from my android device. It is working fine with my API if I try it with the postman.

[image]

This code I'm using which is not working

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("students/driver/signup")
    fun driverSignUp(
        @Part licenseImg: MultipartBody.Part, @Part insuranceImg: MultipartBody.Part,
        @Part vehicleImg: MultipartBody.Part, @Part("driver") driver: Driver
    ): Call<Void>
```

I have `Driver` model class with `SerializedName` and `Expose` annotation.

I'm getting this error when sending request from the android I'm using golang in my backend
`schema: invalid path "driver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your class driver could not be a Part.

you should send a json representing the Driver and the service will be

```
@Multipart
@POST("students/driver/signup")
fun driverSignUp(
    @Part licenseImg: MultipartBody.Part, @Part insuranceImg: MultipartBody.Part,
    @Part vehicleImg: MultipartBody.Part, @Part driver: MultipartBody.Part
): Call<Void>
```

then you'll have to update your service to accept json for driver instead of 4 string representing it

Comment: How should I create `createFormData`?

Comment: to build the driver Part --> 
MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("driver", myDriver.toJson().toString())